# Add and remove columns childs inside Gridview

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-gridview

I write the code to add and remove columns inside Gridview at first load screen everything looks fine but when I remove any column on click the cross button inside the column it breaks the layout and does not remove any column whenever i click to remove column it shows error

Error: SliverGeometry is not valid: The "maxPaintExtent" is less than the "paintExtent".

Error Image: [Error of layout during click/remove item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5KOx.png)

Here is my code :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/utils/widget_functions.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/custom/BorderIcon.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/screens/Relation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
  home: new Photos(),
));
}

class Photos extends StatefulWidget {
 var usrid;

 Photos({Key? key, @required this.usrid}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _Photos createState() => _Photos();
}

class _Photos extends State<Photos>{

 int counter = 0;
 //List<Widget> _list = new List<Widget>();
 List<Widget> _list = <Widget> [];


 @override
 void initState() {

  for(int i =0;  i < 4; i++){
        Widget child = _newItem(i);
        _list.add(child);
  }
 }

 void on_Clicked() {
  Widget child = _newItem(counter);
  setState(() => _list.add(child));
}

Widget _newItem(int i) {
 Key key = new Key('item_${i}');
 Column child = Column(
    key: key,
    children: [
      Stack(
          children:  [
            Card(
              elevation: 0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffa1a1a1),
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                //width: 300,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(child:
                Icon(
                  Icons.image,
                  color: Color(0xffcccccc),
                  size: 60,
                ),

                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 9,
              right: 9,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => _removeItem(key),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  width: 20,
                  'assets/images/close.svg',
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]
      ),
    ]
);
counter++;
return child;
}

void _removeItem(Key key){
 for(int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++){
  Widget child = _list.elementAt(i);
  if(child.key == key){
    setState(() => _list.removeAt(i));
    print('Removing ${key.toString()}');
  }
 }
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Photos'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),

  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(onPressed: on_Clicked, child: new 
  Icon(Icons.add),),

  body: new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: GridView(
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                  //childAspectRatio: 2/1,
                ),
                children: _list,
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
  ),
);
}


}
```

And here is my output:- [Output image of code where clearly see add and remove functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXtHo.png)

Please help out how I did this task and how I add and remove columns inside Gridview
anyone, please help me.

And this is what I need to do:- [this is actual layout i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnbbS.png)
So please help me

Comment: aren't you using null-safety?

Comment: where should use this?

Comment: Seems like your code-snippet is not using dart-null safety.

Comment: but it doesn't show me the null safety error. how it seems like with null safety can you show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not operate the widget directly but data instead. What you should store in the list is the data (image URL or some string, which can be a very complex data structure) you want to present in the view and make the view respond to the changes happening on the object list with flutter's `setState` function.

try this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Photos(),
  ));
}

class Photos extends StatefulWidget {
  var usrid;

  Photos({Key? key, @required this.usrid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Photos createState() => _Photos();
}

class _Photos extends State<Photos> {
  int counter = 0;
  //List<Widget> _list = new List<Widget>();
  List<String> _list = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      _list.add("your data -obj");
    }
  }

  void on_Clicked() {
    setState(() => _list.add("your data -obj"));
  }

  Widget _newItem(int i) {
    Key key = new Key('item_${i}');
    Column child = Column(key: key, children: [
      Stack(children: [
        Card(
          elevation: 0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xffa1a1a1),
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            //width: 300,
            height: 80,
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.image,
                color: Color(0xffcccccc),
                size: 60,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 9,
          right: 9,
          child: InkWell(onTap: () => _removeItem(i), child: Text('close')),
        )
      ]),
    ]);
    counter++;
    return child;
  }

  void _removeItem(int i) {
    print("====remove $i");

    print('===Removing $i');
    setState(() => _list.removeAt(i));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Photos'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: on_Clicked,
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: GridView(
                    //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                      //childAspectRatio: 2/1,
                    ),
                    children: List.generate(_list.length, (index) {
                      //generating tiles with people from list
                      return _newItem(index);
                    })))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with how do I add a new column after the end of the loop inside Gridview. I need to add a column after every end of the looping column where I set the add functionality and remove iadd from floatingActionButton.

Comment: @RAFAlgowid I suggest you open a new StackOverFlow question, and describe both your effort and the problem you are facing.